# How to upload commit (modified) data to the sever

Tags: git

I have a git on the sever [URL] http://XXXXXXXXX

I have commited in my PC, however, I don't know how update to the sever.

I want the command line.

Comment: We need more information. Do you have git installed on the server, or do you actually have git repository there? How did you create your repository? Using `git clone` or using `git init`?

Comment: the sever have been installed git.
I have create my repository by using git clone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first add your repository on the server as a remote with

```
git remote add origin http://XXXXXXXX/repo.git
```

where origin is the name for the repository on the server

then push to it with

```
git push origin master
```

where origin is the name of your previously added repository and master is the branch where you want to push to.